# Getting Error in vuetify.min.css expected '}' got :

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-loader

I am trying to use vuetify framework in my existing project, i installed all the dependencies and added rules in webpack but I am getting an error while using vuetify.min.css file.
My webpack file is:

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProd
    ? false
    : '#cheap-module-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'public': path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
    }
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/, // avoid webpack shimming process
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          compilerOptions: {
            preserveWhitespace: false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: isProd
          ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: { minimize: true }
                },
                'stylus-loader'
              ],
              fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
            })
          : ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
            // Requires >= sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 300000,
    hints: isProd ? 'warning' : false
  },
  plugins: isProd
    ? [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compress: { warnings: false }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'common.[chunkhash].css'
        })
      ]
    : [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
      ]
}
```

and My main.js file is:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { createRouter } from './router';
import { createStore } from './store';
import { createI18n } from './i18n';
var VueCookie = require('vue-cookie');
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync';
import titleMixin from './util/title';
import * as filters from './util/filters';
import Tabs from 'vue-tabs-component';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.use(Tabs);


// mixin for handling title
Vue.mixin(titleMixin)

Vue.use(VueCookie)

// register global utility filters.
Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => {
  Vue.filter(key, filters[key])
})

// Expose a factory function that creates a fresh set of store, router,
// app instances on each call (which is called for each SSR request)
export function createApp () {
  // create store and router instances
  const router = createRouter()
  const store = createStore()
  const i18n = createI18n()

  // sync the router with the vuex store.
  // this registers `store.state.route`
  sync(store, router)

  // create the app instance.
  // here we inject the router, store and ssr context to all child components,
  // making them available everywhere as `this.$router` and `this.$store`.
  const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    i18n,
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    render: h => h(App)
  })

  // expose the app, the router and the store.
  // note we are not mounting the app here, since bootstrapping will be
  // different depending on whether we are in a browser or on the server.
  return { app, router, store }
}
```

Getting error is:
[image]

I must be missing something in the configuration, but I don't know what. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using stylus-loader for plain css?